# Statistical power of t-test in mildly skewed dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I'm trying to learn when I can use t-test if data set is not normal "enough".

Here are the things that I know, please verify:

1. T-test is still robust when data is mildly skewed and light tailed.
2. Mann-Whitney test for medians is a better choice when data has high skewness, or heavy tailed
3. T-test can still be used even with high skewness, and heavy tails, as long as you have large sample sizes. But it has less statistical power than Mann-Whitney test.

From [here](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/261/), they say:

> It is helpful to note that as the sample size n increases, the T ratio: $$T = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{s/\sqrt{N}}$$ approaches an approximate normal distribution regardless of the distribution of the original data.

Question 1: How does the equation for $T$ approach normal distribution?

Question 2: What is the "statistical power" that people talk about? Does it give information about how many sample sizes that I need to have a meaningful result from t-test?

Question 3: Is there any way to determine sample size needed for t-test? Like, if you have skewness of $x$ and kurtosis of $y$, you need $n$ sample size for the result from t-test to be valid, even when your data is non-normal

Comment: If assumptions for a t test are met, then you can use the noncentral t distribution to find the power of a t test against various alternatives. When assumptions are not met, power formulas may be difficult or impossible to find, but usually it is possible to do a simulation to approximate the power against a specific alternative.

Comment: About (3): Wilcoxon signed rank test is appropriate for one-sample tests. Because this test uses ranks, mild skewness is not a problem. In many cases, loss of power (compared with t test) is small. See Addendum to my Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will address the computation of the power of a one-sample t test.
Suppose we wish to use $n = 20$ observations from a normal distribution
to test $H_0: \mu = 110$ against $H_a: \mu < 110$ at the 5% level. Then
we will reject $H_0$ when the t statistic $T = \frac{\bar X - 110}{S/\sqrt{20}} < -1.729,$ where $S$ is the sample standard deviation and $-1.729$ cuts probability $0.05$ from the lower tail of the distribution $\mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1 = 19).$ [Computation in R.]

```
c = qt(.05, 19);  c
[1] -1.729133
```

In order to do a power computation, we need to make a guess at the unknown sample standard deviation $\sigma$ and to choose a particular
value $\mu_a < \mu_0 = 100$ for the computation. If we use $\sigma = 15$ and $\mu_a = 100,$ then we can run a simulation based on many samples
of size $n = 10$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_a = 100, \sigma = 15)$ and see
in what proportion of the samples we reject with $T < c = -1.729.$

```
set.seed(1776);  m=10^6; n=20; mu.0=110; mu.a=100; sg=15
t = replicate(m, 
              t.test(rnorm(n, mu.a, sg), mu = mu.0, alt="less")$stat)
mean(t <= c)
[1] 0.890277
```

So the power is about 89%.  Obviously, in this simulation the t statistics computed by `t.test` and captured using `$`-notation do
not have Student's t distribution with 19 degrees of freedom.

```
lbl = "Simulated Alternative Dist'n of T"
hist(t, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=lbl)
  abline(v = -1.728, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
  curve(dt(x, 19, -2.9814), add=T, lwd=2)
```

[image]

The actual distribution of the t statistic $T$ is a noncentral t distribution with 19 degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter
$\lambda = \sqrt{n}(\mu_0 - \mu_a)/\sigma = -2.9814,$ the density function of which is plotted above.

```
lam = sqrt(20)*(-10)/15 = lam
[1] -2.981424
```

This means that we can find the exact power $0.8902$ in R, without simulation, using the code below:

```
pt(c, 19, lam)
[1] 0.8902459
```

Thus by using the noncentral t distribution, you can make a power curve,
showing the power against a sequence of alternative values $\mu_a.$
Also, by trying various sample sizes, you can find the $n$ required to
achieve the desired power against a particular alternative.

However, if your data are not normal, then neither the regular nor the noncentral t distribution is applicable. It may be difficult to find
a formula for the exact power. Nevertheless, you can use the simulation method with appropriate distributions to find approximate power.
Similar simulation methods could be used to investigate the power of
a nonparametric test.

**Addendum.** (1) Using a Wilcoxon signed rank test instead of a t test with 20 observations  from a normal population.

Suppose you worry that normal data are not normal and use a one-sample test instead of a t test. What happens to the power? We use the same null and alternative hypotheses above, and seek power against the alternative that the distribution is centered at 100.

We don't seek a formula in terms of the distribution of the Wilcoxon test statistic, so we use simulation. Specifically, we use the implementation of the Wilcoxon test in R, capture its P-value at each iteration, and express rejection in terms of P-values below $0.05.$ The power is 87.4%, compared with power 89.0% for the t test.

```
set.seed(2019)
pv = replicate(10^6, 
         wilcox.test(rnorm(20,100,15), mu=110, alt="l")$p.val)
mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.874229
```

(2) Using a Wilcoxon signed rank test instead of a t test when 20 observations are from a moderately right-skewed distribution.

A slightly, but noticeably, skewed distribution results from taking the third power of a normal sample with positive elements. Very roughly speaking, the cube of observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=4.63, \sigma=0.232)$ has $\mu \approx 100, \sigma \approx 15.$ Also the cube of observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(4.783, .0.217)$ has $\mu \approx 110, \sigma \approx 15.$

The following simulation illustrates that with $H_0: \mu = 110$ and $H_a: \mu < 100$ a t.test
at the 5% level, using such slightly skewed data, has power about 88% against the alternative
$\mu_a = 100.$ Similarly, a Wilcoxon signed rank test also has power about 88%. So for 20 observations from the moderately skewed population mentioned above, the t test loses its
slight power advantage over the Wilcoxon test.

```
set.seed(705)
pv = replicate(10^6, 
       t.test(rnorm(20,4.63,.232)^3, mu=110, alt="l")$p.val)
mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.877868

set.seed(705)
pv = replicate(10^6, 
       wilcox.test(rnorm(20,4.63,.232)^3, mu=110, alt="l")$p.val)
mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.877091
```

The first iteration in each simulation is shown below:

```
set.seed(705)
x = rnorm(20, 4.63, .232)^3 ; mean(x); sd(x)
[1] 104.0221
[1] 15.34042
t.test(x, mu=110, alt="less")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -1.7427, df = 19, p-value = 0.04877
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 110
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf 109.9534
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 104.0221 

wilcox.test(x, mu=110, alt="less")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 61, p-value = 0.0527
alternative hypothesis: true location is less than 110
```

Comment: (+1) The cube of observations of a $N(4.63, 0.732)$ rv have mean 106.7 and an sd of 49.4. To get a mean of 100 and an sd of 15 for the cubed observations, you'd need $N(4.64, 0.232)$. Probably just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for catching this! I had `> x = rnorm(10^6, 4.63, .232)^3;  mean(x); sd(x)`, which returns 100.005 and 14.9921, but mistyped from my bad handrwiting. Fortunately I got it right in the simulation code. Made correction in text.

Comment: You give $\mu = 110$ and $\mu < 110$ in the first paragraph. Should it be $100$ for both?

Comment: No, but there was a typo in the $T$-statistic just below that. Now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused how you concluded that the distribution you simulated with `set.seed(1776);` is not t-distribution from the statistical power of 89%. Are you implying that the statistical power should've resulted in 95% if its t-distribution, but since it didn't, you knew that its not t-distribution without visualizing it?

Comment: I also read that statistical power of 80% is good in general. How is the 80% power related to 95% confidence interval?

Comment: (1) Judgment that it's not a t distribution based of its obviously asymmetrical shape. But that's no surprise, because dist'n of t stat is _noncentral_ (not ordinatry) t when alternative is true. (2) What is 'good' power depends on how much risk you can bear of not rejecting when $H_0$ false. Also on budget: higher powers require larger sample sizes. (3) Hard to compare 95% confidence with 80% power. Roughly, more data leads to shorter CIs and higher powers. // Some people test hypotheses by looking at CIs: If null value not included in 95% CI, then Reject null hypothesis at level 5%.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed at length on this site.  The t-test is not very robust to skewness.  For example, with the log-normal distribution a sample size of 50,000 is not large enough for the t-based method to be sufficiently accurate.  The Wilcoxon signed-rank one-sample test does not test a median.  The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test is a two-sample test.  The Wilcoxon tests are 0.95 as efficient as the t-based methods if normality holds, and can be arbitrarily more powerful than this parametric counterpart when normality does not hold.  I suggest reading an intro nonparametric statistics book.

Comment: I'm aware that t-test is not robust to skewness, because they were discussed at length on this site, and I read a lot of them. But again, it all depends on how bad the skewness is. If skewness is mild, it can be overcome by large sample size (or so I read). The question is, how do I know what "mild" is? And how many sample size do I need to overcome that? Can the needed sample size be quantified in context of statistical power?

Comment: Everyone says it "depends on how bad the skewness is", but no body suggest an way to define what "mild skew vs bad skew" quantitatively. As you said, with log-normal distribution, sample size of 50,000 is not enough because its completely asymmetric, but what if skewness is small? Then 50,000 is certainly good enough (though not perfect)

Comment: I would use methods that don't care, staying away when possible from using any method that assumes the standard deviation is a good measure of dispersion.  SD assumes symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the equation for  approach normal distribution?

Well, that it isn't quite true.  The sampling distribution for that statistic approaches a standard normal in the limit as n grows large.  That is very different.  T

> What is the "statistical power" that people talk about? Does it give information about how many sample sizes that I need to have a meaningful result from t-test?

Power is the probability of correctly rejecting the null hypothesis when it is false.  If there really is a difference between groups, then a high powered test will correctly identify that there is a difference upon repetition of the experiment.

Power is an essential part of a sample size calculation.  The sample size depends on a few other things (namely the effect size and the noise in the data), but generally speaking more power requires more samples (all else constant).

> Is there any way to determine sample size needed for t-test? Like, if you have skewness of  and kurtosis of , you need  sample size for the result from t-test to be valid, even when your data is non-normal

Not to my knowledge.  The equations for sample sizes lean heavily on the assumptions of the t-test, and so I don't think there are formulae which make use of higher moments.